# 2nd order differential circuit, converting to S

Tags: differential, passive-networks

[image]

when converting to S domain, the general rule (1/LC)*i* = 2*t* 
how come this does not equal to 2*i* just like (1/LC)*i*L = 2*i*L?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It does..  Rephrase your question.  It is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Where does 2t come from - is i(t) a unit ramp?

Comment: sorry for any confusion, the 2t was because of a unit ramp

Answer (score 1):

The LT of the differential equation is obtained from the relationship \$\large\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\rightarrow \small sY(s)\$, giving: $$(s^2+3s+2)I_L(s)=\frac{2}{s^2}$$